# Typescript tells me method is property and can't create Object

Tags: arrays, typescript

iam new to typescript and don't understand the following behaviour. I have an interface like this:

```
import { Titles } from "../enumerations/titles";

/**
 * Representing a Person
 */
export interface Person{
    id: number;
    title: Titles
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    getName(): string;
}
```

And now I want to create an Const Array for mocking some Employees. Therefore I got this class:

```
import { Person } from "../interfaces/person";
import { Titles } from "../enumerations/titles";

/**
 * Represents an Employee
 */
export class Employee implements Person{
    id: number;
    title: Titles
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    
    getName(): string {

        if (this.title === Titles.Nothing){
            return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
        }

        return this.title + " " + this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;        
    }
}
```

And the Constant:

```
import { Titles } from "../enumerations/titles";
import { Person } from "../interfaces/person";

export const PROJECTMANAGER: Employee[] = [
    { id: 1, title: Titles.Nothing, firstName: "Max", lastName: "Mustermann" },
    { id: 2, title: Titles.Nothing, firstName: "Willy", lastName: "Brandt" },
    { id: 3, title: Titles.Dr, firstName: "Walter", lastName: "Steinmeier" }
];
```

The precompiler told me that this can't work, because Property getName isn't declared in my example values. But this is a Method I just want to initilize some Persons to fill the array.

> The Type "({ id: number; title: Titles.Nothing; firstName: string; lastName: string; } | { id: number; titl..." cannot be assigned to "Employee[]".
>
> The Property "getName" is missed in Type "{ id: number; title: Titles.Nothing; firstName: string; lastName: string; }".

Someone can help? I'm sure it's stupid but I'm stucking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that object literals are not instances of the class `Employee`. In order to create an instance of `Employee` you need to use the `new` operator ( `new Employee()` ).

Since typescript uses structural compatibility to determine type compatibility, you can assign an object literal if you provide ALL the members of the class. But the object literal will still not be an instance of the class:

```
let emp: Employee =  { 
    id: 1, title: Titles.Nothing, firstName: "Max", lastName: "Mustermann",
    getName : Employee.prototype.getName
} // This is ok, we have the getName  member

console.log(emp instanceof Employee) /// Still false, not an instance since we did not create it using new Employee
```

A better option would be to provide a constructor that accepts the object literal as a parameter an use that:

```
export class Employee implements Person{
    constructor (data: Partial<Employee>) {
        Object.assign(this, data);
    }
    /// ....
}


let emp: Employee =  new Employee({ 
    id: 1, title: Titles.Nothing, firstName: "Max", lastName: "Mustermann",
});

console.log(emp instanceof Employee) /// True now
```

Comment: Thank you wasn't aware the there is a difference between objects and classes.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Employee` is a class, not a simple object, you need to create new `Employee`s with `new`, not with a simple object declaration.

Define a constructor that takes `id`, `title`, `firstName`, and `lastName` as arguments, then do something like this:

```
export const PROJECTMANAGER: Employee[] = [
    new Employee(1, Titles.Nothing, "Max", "Mustermann"),
    new Employee(2, Titles.Nothing, "Willy", "Brandt"),
    new Employee(3, Titles.Dr, "Walter", "Steinmeier")
];
```